# Updating columns in unix

Tags: file, unix, replace

Need Unix code or script which will provide following results:

Suppose file 1 has following data

```
ABC 1 cvb
DEF 2. bnm
```

And file 2 has following data

```
ABC 3
DEF 4
```

The output file should contain data like

```
ABC 3 cvb
DEF 4 bnm
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$1];print}' file2 file1
ABC 3 cvb
DEF 4 bnm
```

Explained:

```
awk '            # using awk
NR==FNR {        # process first file
    a[$1]=$2     # hash to a on first field
    next         # next record
}
{                # process second file
    $2=a[$1]     # update second field from a hash
    print        # output
}' file2 file1   # mind the order of files
```